# How can I combine multiple function's output(strings) in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

I want to combine strings returned by multiple functions conditionally; somehow it's not working:

**file1.py**

```
CALL_FUNCTION = {
    ‘function1’: function1
}

def function1():
    return “hello”

def function2():
    return “world”
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import CALL_FUNCTION

def final_function(condition):
    final_string=CALL_FUNCTION[‘function1’] #Calls function1 from file1.py
    if(condition)
        from file1 import function2
        final_string += function2() 

    return final_string

final_function(true) #This does not work; no error. Expected output is “hello world” when condition is true
```

Comment: Did you copy-paste the code or type it manually? I get tons of compilation errors ... all your ``'`` and ``"`` are wrong, `if(condition)` is missing a `:`. `true` should be `True`. `CALL_FUNCTION[‘function1’]` is missing a `()` after it. `function1` needs to be defined *before* it gets used in the `CALL_FUNCTION` dict definition. Please test the code you post and then copy-paste it instead of writing it manually.

Comment: try `print(final_function(True))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had lots of minor bugs. I suspect they all happened because you copied the code by manually retyping it, please use the copy-paste function in future problems.

Here is the corrected version of your code:

*file1.py*

```
def function1():
    return "hello"

def function2():
    return "world"

CALL_FUNCTION = {
    'function1': function1
}
```

*file2.py*

```
from file1 import CALL_FUNCTION

def final_function(condition):
    final_string=CALL_FUNCTION['function1']() #Calls function1 from file1.py
    if condition:
        from file1 import function2
        final_string += function2() 

    return final_string

final_function(True) #This does not work; no error. Expected output is “hello world” when condition is true
```

But after that, everything is working. The functions get called, as expected, the function returns 'helloworld', as expected, and nothing gets printed, as expected.

`final_function(True)` would only print something in interactive mode, in batch mode you need to add print() to actually see the result.

```
print(final_function(True))
```

Output:

> helloworld

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return output of different functions as per "condition", you may import both functions and run each in if-else clause.
for example:

In file1.py

```
def func1():
    return "hello"
```

In file2.py

```
def func2():
    return "world"
```

Then in separate file3.py

```
from file1 import func1
from file2 import func2

def func3(cond):
  out = func1()
  if cond:
     out+=' '+func2()

  return out

if __name__ =='__main__':
    print(func3(True))
```

Output :

> `hello world`

Comment: Isn't that what he does? Just in one file?

Comment: @Finomnis, you may write the entire code in 1 file, nothing will change. For the sake of demonstration of multiple file imports, I wrote the code explicitly.

Comment: I get that, but I don't think his question was how to import from multiple files, but why his code doesn't actually print anything. The real answer would be `because there is no print() statement`.

Comment: if you post an answer like this, which partly avoids answering OP's question.. then for coding sake.... include your `if name =='main': print(func3(True))` inside the markup ;p

Comment: Thank you @ZF007 for pointing it out. Will be cautious next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you're saying that there's no error when you're running this code as there's a couple bugs in your code, so I'm suspecting that this isn't the exact code that you've been running. First of all, make sure to define `CALL_FUNCTION` below `function1`. Secondly, there's a couple of syntax errors - use `True` rather than `true` as well as propper string quotes (`'` or `"`).

But I believe that the main issue here is that you're never actually **calling** `function1` and you're trying to concat a function object `final_string` to a string which is a result of calling `function2`. In order to fix that you'd need to replace:

`final_string=CALL_FUNCTION[‘function1’]`

with

`final_string=CALL_FUNCTION[‘function1’]()`

This ensures you call `function1` and save its result to `final_string` instead of saving the function object.

PS: I recommend going over [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in order to make your code cleaner and easier to read for others in the future.

Comment: You should also point out that he never actually calls `print()` on the result. Which is, imo, the real reason why his code seems to do nothing, I think the missin `()` is yet another one of his typos.